# Passing parameters to a subroutine in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90, subroutine

I'm trying to understand how to pass some variables with values, to a subroutine, from another subroutine.

I have the code:

```
program pg
call sub()
end

subroutine sub()
character :: P(12,12)
character :: D(20), N(26), userInput
integer :: A,B

A = 5
B = 2
userInput = "hello"
call test(P,D,N,userInput,A,B)

end subroutine

subroutine test(P,D,N,userInput,A,B)

end subroutine test
```

But that gives me a warning of:

```
Warning: Type mismatch in argument 'p' at (1); passed CHARACTER(1) to REAL(4)
```

I'm not exactly sure on how to get rid of this warning, let alone if the subroutine call is correct (syntax wise). Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should complete the subroutine `test`.  As it stands you haven't declared the types of the arguments there, so default typing rules are used.  It looks like your compiler is checking the interfaces and finding they don't match.

Comment: I'm pretty new to fortran, how would I declare the types of arguments there? I actually don't really know how to do that.

Comment: That's possibly a little too broad to answer here, but the [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/fortran/1106/procedures-functions-and-subroutines#t=20170206030408357924) may be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, why this error is happening: You have not explicitly declared any variables in subroutine `test` so by default, the `IMPLICIT` variable type rules are applied - variables starting with `[A-H,O-Z]` are treated as single-precision reals (`REAL(4)`) and the remainder (starting with `[I-N]`) are integers. In this case, the real arguments to `test` are `P`, `D`, `userInput`, `A`, and `B`; `N` is treated as an integer. Also these are all treated as scalar quantities since no dimension information is provided in `test`.

In subroutine `sub`, the variable `P` is declared as a 12-by-12 array of length-1 strings (single characters or `CHARACTER(1)`). This explains why you're getting the type mismatch error.

Advice: Read up on the `IMPLICIT` statement and start your code with `IMPLICIT NONE`, always. This forces you to declare all your variables. This slight inconvenience allows the compiler to catch typos and namespace collisions and is considered best practice. It won't solve your next problem (`P`, `D`, and `N` are arrays passed in as arguments to a routine which expects them to be scalars) but it will get rid of the type mismatch error.

For bonus points, look into the `INTENT` attribute for argument declarations. If you know that certain arguments are read-only or will only have their values set within a routine, you can declare them as `INTENT(IN)` or `INTENT(OUT)`. This is an added guard against accidentally changing read-only variables or reading variables before they've been initialized.